# Is there a closed formula for $b$ in $2 \sum_{n=1}^{x-1} \sum_{i=n+1}^x (-1)^{n+i} \frac{\cos(b \ln(\frac{n}{i}))}{\sqrt{n}}$?

Tags: number-theory

I was wondering if there was a closed formula for b such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} 2 \sum_{n=1}^{x-1} \sum_{i=n+1}^x (-1)^{n+i} \frac{\cos(b \ln(\frac{n}{i}))}{\sqrt{n}} = - \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}$$
(The partial sums approach each other is what I mean).

I tried reasoning using integrals.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt + \frac{1}{x} = \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}$$
Then maybe this follows.
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} 2 \int_{1}^{x-1} \int_{t+1}^x (-1)^{t+j} \frac{\cos(b \ln(\frac{t}{j}))}{\sqrt{t}} dj dt = \ln\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) - \frac{1}{x}$$But there are two problems.

**1.)** I have absolutely no idea how to evaluate this, and

**2.)** I don't know whether or not using integrals is valid.

This leads me to conclude that someone with more number theory knowledge is required to attempt this.

**Motivation:** I took a look at the graphs and found this.
The black line is the harmonic series and green in the above function.

Here is when $b=19$ (there is no correlation)

[image]

And then when $b=21$:
[image]

And then again when $b=25$
[image]

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Can you explain the first line? You are saying the limit of a function as $x$ approaches $\infty$ is equal to a function dependent on $x$, and which diverges to $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: I don't really know. I saw it on a blackboard when I came into class early and graphed it. I noticed that it periodically converged to what looked like the harmonic series, and now I'm here. @CarlSchildkraut

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated I clarified in the question